# How to show "use default values" on all stores view in magento2?

Tags: product, magento2.4.1, product-edit

I am facing an issue.

1. I want to show "use default values" on all store view in special price from and to fields only.
2. Suppose I have a website with two stores. "use default values" check boxes are shown fine when I select individual stores but when I select " All Stores View" it is not showing on all fields or specific.

For example if scope is all store view
[image]

Please answer if you have worked on or if you have any idea.

thanks

2. result should be this;
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Is this an issue within the admin panel? "Use default values" is displayed as `special_from_date` and `special_to_date` attributes are set at "Website" scope. Do you want to define a single value that's inherited to all stores? If so, you may want to create a new attribute at global scope?

More info on scope can be found here:

- https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-admin/start/setup/websites-stores-views.html#scope-settings

Comment: I have updated question please look.